# Brother MFC Scanner not recognized any more

Tags: macos, high-sierra, printing, scanning

I have a Brother MFC-1910W connected by WIFI (multi functional wireless b/w laser printer, scanner and fax). Since a few days I cannot use the scanner any more.

In the first place the scanner icon was disabled so I decided to remove and add the printer. Since than the whole scanner icon disappeared as if the MFC has no scanner capabilities.

I have Brother driver 4.0.5 installed. I found a scanner 4.2.0 on [brother support site](http://support.brother.com/g/b/productseries.aspx?c=de&lang=de&content=dl&pcatid=3#Series-58) (sorry, page not available in [english](http://support.brother.com/g/b/productseries.aspx?c=us&lang=en&content=dl&pcatid=3)). From that installation on I cannot connect using bonjour any more but using IP but still no scanner available.

Now the best: Accessing from another MacBook (both running 10.13.2) there is no problem. It seems some printer driver installation or preferences are broken.

Any idea how to fix, cleanup, whatever (maybe an option to reset all printer driver info would be fine)?

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same problem with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 on a MacBook Pro 13" 2018 and a Brother MFC-j6510DW.

The solution is straightforward, you have to reset the printing system according to the Apple support document, [macOS Sierra: Reset the printing system](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25565)

Go to `System Preferences → Printers & Scanners`:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd> click in the list at the left, then choose **Reset printing system...** from the context menu that appears.
2. After you reset the printing system, the list of printers in Printers & Scanners preferences is empty.
3. Re-add any printers

That's all.

Comment: NB I had to click the little "Click lock to make changes" before it would let Reset printing system be "not greyed out"

Comment: resetting worked perfectly with a DCP-7065DN using Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: Works at first but after reboot it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was updating the firmware of the device using the newest "Brother Firmware Update Tool" from their official website.