# Scanner not appearing in macOS 10.13 High Sierra over network

Tags: high-sierra, scanning, peripheral

My multifunction Printer / Scanner doesn't have any scanning functions available under macOS 10.13 High Sierra while connected over network.

The scanner function worked over network under macOS 10.10 Yosemite.

The scanner is detected by Image Capture only when connected via USB.

Resetting the print system from the instructions in this question has not solved the problem: [Brother MFC Scanner not recognized any more](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311278/brother-mfc-scanner-not-recognized-any-more/333436#333436)

- Brother MFC-9335CDW
- macOS 10.13.6
- Driver version 4.1.2

[image]

Under macOS 10.10 Yosemite there was a "Scan" button on the top-right of the panel in the picture above while connected over network.

The Scan button appears in macOS 10.13 High Sierra only when the device is connected via USB.

[image]

I can add the scanner portion separately to the MFC over network ie. it's recognized, but when I try to use it in Image Capture it gives an error that the software isn't installed. If I try to allow it to install software available from Apple automatically it fails to install.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Brother iPrint&Scan says the device is not supported...?
[image]

If the printer is added using Airport driver the result is the same as using the CUPS driver over network:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Image Capture app?

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks, I tried but it's not appearing in Image Capture. I have a feeling this might be because it's connected via network rather than USB though.

Comment: Brother MFC-9335CDW supports AirPrint (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311 and https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=mfc9335cdw_as&ftype3=2018&faqid=faq00002727_002), so you may want to set it up as an AirPrint printer, see the "Add a Wi-Fi or network printer" section at https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/add-a-printer-mh14004/11.0/mac/11.0 for details. My experience is that AirPrint not only provides printing but additional functionality like scanning in supported printers. Note that AirPrint works with Wi-Fi or wired network connections.

Comment: Thanks @jaume ! I gave it a shot, unfortunately the airprint driver (also IPP) doesn't provide scanning functions over the network either :/ I wonder if there's a port I can check that might be being blocked? I don't think there's an active firewall on my system but it would be nice to check the port is reachable if that could possibly be the issue.

Comment: I don't think it is a firewall issue, and I'm surprised it didn't work, according to the link in my previous comment, the Brother documentation states that  "you can print or scan with your Brother machine in two ways: Brother iPrint&Scan app and AirPrint." After adding the AirPrint printer, was it named similarly to "Brother MFC-9335CDW-Airprint" (that is, suffixed with "AirPrint") in the Printers & Scanners preference pane?

Comment: @jaume iPrint&Scan doesn't allow scanning either, I've added screenshots & notes of everything I've tried to the body of the question. The "Kind" type has airprint suffix

Comment: Thank you for adding the screenshots, the scanner seems to be listed as a separate device named MFC-9335CDW. Can you select it in the "Add" window and press "Add", or alternatively, select it in the "Printers & Scanners" window (which will possibly result in the scanner being installed)?

Comment: @jaume Yeah, gave that a shot but it didn't work either. Pics are in the body, it's getting a bit busy / long so here are the relevant ones: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7kL8.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj1De.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYZ1Z.png . It doesn't get any further than that.

Comment: Too bad it didn't work. Have you tried installing the scanner driver for macOS 10.13 from https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=mfc9335cdw_as&os=10045? You may want to install the full software package for full printing and scanning support.

Comment: @jaume Thanks, I've tried both the Full Software Package and the Scanner Driver downloads. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a difference in behaviour.

Comment: Sorry to read that, it seems the scanner is not supported in macOS 10.13.

Comment: @jaume no worries, thanks for all your assistance :)