# My Brother printer not working in macOS Big Sur(11.3.1)

Tags: macos, time-machine, ms-office, big-sur, printing

Help me please
I bought my new printer Brother MFC-1910W yesterday.
I'm trying to install driver and print my work by Microsoft Word but not working.

I checked information in Brother Website seem like MFC-1910W not support macOS Big Sur(11.3.1) but I'm not sure.
I don't know what should to do with my new printer. So sad

Everyone help me please

Comment: Have you try this : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reset-mac-printing-system-solve-a-problem-mh14001/mac ?

Comment: I'd recommend that you return the printer and purchase one that supports AirPrint (a very convenient feature in macOS (and iOS) that supports printing without installing printer-specific drivers). Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Brother recommends using AirPrint with Big Sur. [Unfortunately, your model does not support AirPrint.](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=th&lang=en&prod=mfc1910w_eu_as&faqid=faq00002865_000) As an alternative, Brother recommends you download `Brother iPrint&Scan` from the Apple App Store. Note: Most reviews for the `Brother iPrint&Scan` software are not very good.

When viewing the [Downloads webpage](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc1910w_eu_as&os=10065), there is no printer driver available for macOS 11. Therefore I would assume Brother will not be releasing a printer driver for your current macOS 11.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

**The good news** is that the [Brother MFC-1910W](https://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc1910w_eu_as) fully supports macOS 11 "Big Sur", as you can see in the printer's [Supported OS](https://support.brother.com/g/b/oslist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc1910w_eu_as) page:

[image]

**The bad news** is that the printer doesn't support [AirPrint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPrint), a feature in macOS (and iOS) that supports printing without installing printer-specific drivers. In my experience, AirPrint is especially convenient for [MFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-function_printer)s because of its support for scanning.

I'd recommend that you return the printer and purchase one that supports AirPrint. Check Apple's [AirPrint device list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311) for a complete list of supported devices.

If that's not an option, you will have to install [iPrint&Scan](https://apps.apple.com/app/brother-iprint-scan/id1193539993?l=en&mt=12) from the Mac App Store (the [Mobile Print/Scan Guide for Brother iPrint&Scan (Apple Devices)](https://download.brother.com/welcome/doc100144/cv_eng_mpg_ios_b.pdf), although it applies to iPhones/iPads, may be helpful).

Comment: Did you bother to read the document [Mobile Print/Scan Guide for Brother iPrint&Scan (Apple Devices)](https://download.brother.com/welcome/doc100144/cv_eng_mpg_ios_b.pdf)? This is not for Macs, but to mobile devices such as phones.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, I had a quick look and noticed from the screenshots in the App Store that the apps are similar, but have edited my answer to make it clear that the linked document applies to mobile devices.

Comment: IMO, the correct answer is your recommendation to get a printer that is more Mac (Big Sur) compatible.

Comment: I'm confused. If Brother claims compatibility with BigSur why does it require additional apps to work?

Comment: @nohillside seems to be a recurring issue with Brother https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418416/scanner-not-appearing-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra-over-network

Comment: @nohillside I'd say is compatible in the sense that Big Sur+iPrint&Scan is a supported configuration (albeit not a user-friendly one). What bothers me is that the printer's Downloads page falsely claims that it supports AirPrint, while another support document elsewhere on the Brother website says it doesn't (check David Anderson's answer). I fell for that in the first version of my answer. I think the MFC-1910W is circling the drain as it has been discontinued (at least) in the UK, and, in that market, Brother recommends an AirPrint-compatible printer instead. Hence my recommendation.